# Devonthink Sorter bug

Tags: macos, organizer-software

Resizing the Sorter panel increases the number of boxes in the grid, but on reaching a certain size, the Sorter promptly disappears!

No amount of quitting and starting seems to bring the Sorter back, not even rebooting the computer. Anyone else faced the same problem?

I use Devonthink Pro Office on a Mac Snow Leopard.

Comment: While we can provide workaround, you're more likely to get it fixed if you contact their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on Mac OS X Lion. It only happens with Sorter docked to the right side of the screen. So, as a workaround, just keep it on the left side.

To fix Sorter, so you can use it again, quit Sorter via the preferences pane in DevonThink Pro.

[image]

Then open `~/Library/Preferences/com.devon-technologies.think-sorter.plist` in an appropriate `.plist` editor such as Xcode, and delete the entries `NSWindow Frame Default.sorter` and `gridFrame`.

[image]

Now, start Sorter again from the same preferences pane in DTP.

If you don't have a program that can edit binary `.plist` files, you can also simply delete it. You'll probably lose your full screen preferences (*Hide Sorter in Full Screen*) though.

Comment: Nice :) Works; understandably the groups added to the Sorter are gone. Also the Mac seems to have a default app for opening .plist files called "Property List Editor".

Comment: @pravnar property list editor came with an old version of Xcode and was discontinued.